# jQuery ajax(): can't filter tr append to tbody

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

here my PHP snippet the ajax resquest response foreach;

```
$output = '';
   foreach($result->data as $v){
      $output .= '<tr class="s-container" id="box-'.$v->Code.'">';
         $output .='<td>'.$v->Name.'</td>';
      $output .= '</tr>'; //end s-s-contanier
   } 
echo $output;
```

here Ajax snippet success function

```
.done(function(resultData) {
   var offerData = $(resultData).filter('.s-container');
   $("#offerDispaly tbody").append(offerData);
});
```

Here table html to display the tr

```
<table id="offerDispaly">
<thead>
    <tr>
      <td class="transp"><p><a href="#">Name</a></p></td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    // to append the tr
</tbody>
```

The problem is I can't get the tr to dispaly data, if I change the tr to div he work well

Thank u for help!

Answer (score 0):

use

```
.done(function(resultData) {
     $("#offerDispaly tbody").append(resultData);
});
```

Comment: this append only data not to tr so me i like to get my tr and display